# How to pass an image as argument to a HTTPs callable function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to pass an image from the client to my https callable function...

Until now, what I have been doing is:

1. Upload the image to the storage
2. Then, call my function with the storage image's reference as argument
3. Download the image in the backend

But, this consumes three operations: a write, a cloud function invokation and the image read...

So, as I need to do this the faster as possible, I have thought that it might be possible to pass the image as argument when invoking my cloud function... (the passed file shouldn't have the 10MB limitation, images can have 30MB).

Is it possible? How?

Comment: 1) Your current method is the correct approach for most cases. 2) How big are the images? Cloud Functions has a limit of (IIRC) 32 MB. 3) Use HTTP POST to send an image to Cloud Functions.Example using curl: curl -X POST "https://REGION-PROJECT-ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"Name":"filename", "Data":"Base64-Encoded-Image-Data"}'

Comment: Actually Cloud Functions has an incoming payload limit of 10 MB @JohnHanley. https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits

Comment: @DougStevenson - Thank you. 32 MB is for App Engine/Cloud Run. I should have looked up the limit by commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you require an unlimited size of the file, you aren't going to be able to upload via Cloud Functions, which has an incoming payload limit of 10 MB.

Consider instead writing a [storage trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) the runs immediately after the storage upload finishes.  The function can then choose to download the file to work with it.  With Cloud Functions you will also be limited to downloads less then the size of the total memory available to the function's instance (since the only writable disk space is backed by actual memory).